# Regex trim path to last folder and file

Tags: regex, perl

What I have is this:

```
E:\folder\00000000\file.txt
```

and I want to get this:

```
00000000\file.txt
```

Problem is I am looping over a list of these directories and need to remove it for each one, not just the 00000000 directory because the next is 00000001 and so one

The regex I came up with is this:

```
.+\\00000000
```

which gets me this:

```
\file.txt
```

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks!

Update: Crap! I messed up...

What I want to capture is the opposite of that:

```
E:\folder\
```

So I can substitute it with a different path. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pattern will work: `[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$`

It says: any number of non-forward-slash characters, and then a forward slash, and then more non-forward-slashes, and the end of input or the line.

Comment: I just realized I need to capture the opposite of that so I can substitute it out...sorry for the confusion. Any ideas?

Comment: If you use `(([^\\]+\\)+)([^\\]+\\[^\\]+$)`, the first match group ($1) will contain E:\folder, and the third ($3) will contain what we already matched.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with paths. Use functions designed to deal with paths.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $path = Path::Class::File->new_foreign(
    Win32 => 'E:\folder\00000000\file.txt'
);

my $top = dir($path->volume, $path->parent->dir_list(0, 2));

print "$top\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
E:\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `\\([^\\]+\\[^\\]+)$` and grab `$1`/`\1`

That breaks down to:

- a backslash;
- Keep:

  - at least 1 non-backslash;
  - a backslash;
  - at least 1 non-backslash;
- end of string

N.B. that even if you're on Windows, you can still use a standard slash in filenames, so if you don't have control of the format of the incoming filenames, you might want to instead use:

```
 [\\\/]([^\\\/]+\\[^\\\/]+)$
```

… as this will accept either `\` or `/` as path separators.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trim, match!

```
$path = "E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt";
if ($path =~ /(\d+\\.*)$/) {  
    $result = $1;
    print $result;
} else {
    print "bad";
}
```