# Perl trim path regex

Tags: regex, perl, path

So I am trimming a path that looks like this:

```
E:\folder\00000000\file.txt
```

I want to substitute this:

```
E:\folder\
```

And I cannot come up with the regex to do so.

I did ask this before but got the order mixed around.

Comment: can you provide more information? Do all your paths have the same format? What part of path do you really want to capture using regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex trim path to last folder and file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592751/regex-trim-path-to-last-folder-and-file) **Update the original question with relevant information.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming variable drive names and folders with only underscore/hyphen:

```
/^[A-Z]:\\(\w|_|-)+\\/
```

will match `E:\folder\`

Comment: This worked! As soon as it will let me I will mark it correct! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Manipulating paths with regex sucks.

```
use Path::Class::File qw();
my $path = Path::Class::File->new_foreign('Win32', 'E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt');
# E:\folder\00000000\file.txt
my $base = $path->parent->parent;
# E:\folder
```

Comment: What makes you think foreign is needed here? But more importantly, the question wasn't how to extract E:\folder, but on substituting it.

Comment: Using the plain exported `file` constructor and calling parent on it made me think, it returns `.`, but explicitely telling this is a DOS-ish path always works. - I blame the unclear formulation in the question. I would transfer the upvotes to your answer if I could.

Comment: Nope, `say Path::Class::File->new_foreign('Win32', 'file.txt')->parent` returns `.` too.

Comment: Use the whole path. `$ perl -mPath::Class::File -E'say Path::Class::File->new_foreign(q(Win32), q(E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt))->parent'␊E:\folder\00000000␊$ perl -MPath::Class=file -E'say file(q(E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt))->parent'␊.␊`

Comment: But if you use the whole path, `file` doesn't return `.` either. So Foreign doesn't "always work", and `file` always works as well as Foreign (unless you're actually are on a foreign system).

Comment: Lolwhat, I just showed it does, I'm convinced I'm not seeing ghosts. This is Path::Class 0.24; if you're not getting the same results as me, I can't help it.

Comment: No, you showed that you were using a foreign system. Are you perhaps using the unix emulation layer known as cygwin?

Comment: You're wrong. `> perl -mPath::Class -E "say Path::Class::File->new_foreign(q(Win32), q(E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt))->parent"␊E:\folder\00000000` This is P::C 0.24 on Strawberry. – In conclusion, for those who followed this conversation: When one wants to process a DOS/Windows path, i.e. with backslash as directory separator, and write portable code, then `Path::Class::File->new_foreign('Win32', …` is the suitable constructor because the `file` constructor is system dependent. The `file` constructor works fine (is portable) for Unix path and Windows path with forward slash as separator.

Comment: Of course it returns `E:\folder\00000000`. That's what I said it returns. Why do you say I'm wrong?

Comment: Re "`file` constructor is system dependent". Exactly! That's why it's what you want to use 99.999% of the time. Not using `file` makes your program non-portable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6088/discussion-between-daxim-and-ikegami)

Comment: @damix, Replied to what you left in "chat".

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression
`^(.*[\\/])([^\\/]+[\\/][^\\/]+)$`

`$1` will be equal to `E:\folder\` and `$2` will be equal to `00000000\file.txt`

Comment: Note that Windows pathnames *can* contain the `/` character as well, so using `[\\\/]` is a more paranoid way to handle the separators.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Path::Class qw( file dir );

my $file      = file('E:\\folder\\00000000\\file.txt');
my $orig_base = dir('E:\\folder');
my $new_base  = dir('F:\\directory');

# F:\directory\00000000\file.txt
say $file->relative($orig_base)->absolute($new_base);
```